# CAN communication with ACK bit

Tags: can

I'm new when it comes to CAN communication and the embedded world. I'm working with a TC322 microcontroller and am trying to configure a CAN controller.

As per my understanding:

1. If the receiving node (RX) correctly receives the message frame, it sends an ACK bit to the transmitting node (TX). The ACK bit is a dominant (logic 0) bit that overwrites the recessive (logic 1) bit transmitted by the transmitting node.
2. The transmitting node (TX) checks the ACK bit on the bus. If it detects a dominant ACK bit, it assumes that the message frame was correctly received by the receiving node (RX) and considers the transmission successful.
3. If the transmitting node (TX) does not receive an ACK bit after a specified timeout period, it assumes that the message frame was not correctly received by the receiving node (RX). In this case, the transmitting node (TX) will retransmit the message frame after waiting for a random time period.

[image: oscilloscope screenshot]

In my code, the TX node doesn't receive an ACK bit after sending the 5th msg and generates an Error Frame and retransmits the message.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, and if the waveforms I see on the scilloscope are correct or not.

I connected CANoe to further check the logs and type of error that is generated. There I see the very first message with correct content, and nothing more. There is no log per se.

[image]

Comment: Assuming those are the lines between MCU and the CAN transceiver then it looks ok? High = recessive, low = dominant. Meaning Tx sends ACK recessive and someone answered with a dominant bit. It's perhaps easier to look at the CANH signal where the logical levels are the other way around. You often easily spot the ack bit since the voltage levels between two CAN nodes can differ slightly without going out of spec. Are you sure you are missing an ACK? Error frames can be caused by other things than missing ACK.

Comment: Though I'm not sure what you mean with "If the receiving node (RX)", "The transmitting node (TX)"... please clarify where exactly you are measuring.

Comment: @prafull Could you ask a question?

Comment: Thank you @Lundin for your reply. So basically I'm using burst of 5 CAN messages initially from MCU to configure CAN transceiver (TJA1153). this requires certain messages with command byte order etc. Until CAN transceiver is not configured, messages are not sent over CAN bus ( CAN-H / CAN-L ). This wave forms above are from TX and RX pins from CAN controller before Transceiver starts sending msgs over CAN bus. Receiving node mean RX pin of MCU and Transmitting node is TX pin

Comment: So is this all related to configuring this specialized CAN transceiver? I've never used the secure ones so I can't help you there. However, a traditional CAN bus will require at least one other active node connected to CANH/CANL. I was under the impression that you had that, but perhaps that is not the case?

Comment: @Lundin exactly.! Additional active node ? I'm using CAN 0 node 0 for this. you mean i need another node from same MCU ?

Comment: @prafullmohite I don't know what you mean with "CAN 0 node 0". Basic CAN communication requires at least 2 active CAN controllers on the bus, each with a transceiver. [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251) Alternatively during early prototyping you can put a CAN controller in "loopback" mode and have it speak with itself. Not really recommended, instead I'd recommend to get a CAN listener which can be configured to actively ACK. You'll need one anyway or otherwise you cannot develop CAN applications.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks alot for the article. It helped me understand what was wrong and could pin point in the problem. So basically, i was using CANoe as 2nd node for reception of CAN messages. When CANoe is connected to receive messages then ACK error is not generating anymore and i can see message on CAN bus :)
Thanks alot